# Glyphicons not showing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I have a problem showing bootstrap glyphicons, Chrome developer tools says the fonts are not found (404),

in my css I have the following code:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

The url is correct since I use this map structure:

```
Assets
  -fonts
     -glyphicon fonts
  -css
     -bootstrap.css
```

Comment: JSfiddle or Link please.

Comment: Seems to me as a typo somewhere in your code.

Comment: Fixed it, I had to place my glyphicon fonts files in the public dir and not in my Assets Pipeline dir –

Comment: No, I'm using Laravel